# How to add node/edge attributes from command line for dot/graphviz?

Tags: linux, graphviz, dot

I am trying to add node/edge attributes from command line to edit the graph that is rendered using graphviz. How do I do it?

I am trying to visualize a large undirected graph (~7M nodes) using graphviz. I converted the networkx graph to a dot graph and stored. It doesn't have any attributes to visualize (eg. node color, size, edge width, etc.) I need to add these from command line without editing the dot file since it is too big. The Documentation says I need to use the -Nname for node attributes and -Ename for edge attributes but it doesn't work. Any examples to work with would be great!

(I am trying to visualize it with sfdp)

Thank you!

Comment: The above link gives examples where the styling attributes are given in the dot file itself. But to explore different attributes without editing the actual dot file - how to do that?

Comment: Can't you just include the attributes when generating the dot file?

Comment: Also iirc graphviz had trouble rendering graphs with a few tens of thousands of nodes for me once upon a time.

Comment: It seems to work fine for ~1M nodes.

Comment: gvpr can take a dot file and add attributes.